# How to create a directory and insert a file in that directory in C#?

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm trying to create a directory/folder, and at the same time insert an uploaded document to it. My code works. However, when I upload the file it goes to the same level as the newly created folder but I need it inside of it. How can I achieve that? here's what I have tried:

```
protected void ASPxButtonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
   using (Stream Fstream = e.UploadedFile.FileContent)
   {  
    string folder = NewFile.User;
    string Uploads = Server.MapUploads("~/Uploads/" + e.UploadedFile.FileName);     
    bool same = Directory.Exists(Uploads);  
 
    Fstream fs = new Fstream(Uploads, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);   
            
    if (!same)
    {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Uploads), folder));
      Fstream.CopyTo(fs); //**File that I need to include in the new folder**
    }
  }
}
```

> I appreciate the help, Thanks!

Comment: Your variable names appear to be causing the root of the confusion.  Specifically the `Path` variable.  You use it before you even define it?  Or is there another one defined in another scopr?  Names like `FileStream` and `Path` are a pretty bad idea, since they'll confuse you with *classes* called `FileStream` and `Path`.  Rename your variables and see where you define the `Path` that you're using when you initialize `fs`.  It sounds like you want that value to include the new directory.

Comment: I see! I'll rename them now.

Comment: @David I posted with the new change.And, yes there're other methods... this is simplified version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the destination file stream:

```
new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
```

That `Path` variable is the name of the file to which you're going to write.  But there are a few issues here:

1. You're definining it before you define the folder, so it doesn't include that folder name.
2. You seem to be confusing *directories* with *files* in some of your paths.
3. You seem to be defining *another* variable called `Path` a few lines later, which is probably confusing you.  (And I'm surprised it compiles.)
4. All in all, variable names like `Path` and `FileStream` are a *super* bad idea.  They're not only against C# conventions, but more importantly they're guaranteed to confuse you because those are also the names of *classes* that you're using.  (Again, I'm surprised this even compiles.)

First and foremost, rename your variables to something more sensible.  Good naming helps everything else in the code, because it helps you understand the code.

After that, don't define the target file stream until you need to use it, and define it with the full path you want to use.  It looks like the whole process should simply be to check if the folder exists, create it if it doesn't, and then write the file.  Nothing more complex than that.

Untested, but perhaps something like this:

```
// define your paths
string rootFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Path/");
string outputFolder = Path.Combine(rootFolder, NewFile.User);
string targetFile = Path.Combine(outputFolder, e.UploadedFile.FileName);

// create the directory if needed
if (!Directory.Exists(outputFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
}

// write the file
using (Stream inputFS = e.UploadedFile.FileContent)
{
    FileStream outputFS = new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    inputFS.CopyTo(outputFS);
}
```

Keep your names clear, keep your operations simple.  There's no need to over-complicate any of it.

Comment: There's a missing character in the if condition. I'll use your suggestions and let you know soon. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! this works. It's a better approach and more clean.